# AliPay android integration with proper document in english?

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway, payment, alipay

I am doing some research work on AliPay, after spending 4 hour still not geting any proper document to integrate with android.

Here is reference link to get sample demo and sdk.

https://doc.open.alipay.com/doc2/detail.htm?treeId=54&articleId=104509&docType=1

```
public static final String APPID = "";
public static final String PID = "";
public static final String TARGET_ID = "";
public static final String RSA2_PRIVATE = "";
public static final String RSA_PRIVATE = "";
```

Not find proper value for it,  how to give value for this all.

Here is one more reference link where i getting PID, RSA For Sandbox.
https://global.alipay.com/help/integration/23

After Run this sample demo, its not login or validation on mobile it say "Server busy, try after some time."

AliPay Testing or Development is possible from India ?

Comment: see the Supported Currency List [https://global.alipay.com/help/integration/25](https://global.alipay.com/help/integration/25)

Answer (score 0):

In alipay Supported Currency [List](https://global.alipay.com/help/integration/25) there are no indian currency

here is ther Error Code [list](https://global.alipay.com/service/app/14)

and here is the RSA Key Generation with OpenSSL https://global.alipay.com/service/app/16

and here the full integration [guide](https://global.alipay.com/service/app/4)
and here [integrationGuide](https://globalprod.alipay.com/order/integrationGuide.htm)
hope this will help